# Selecting an item from dropdown menu by using RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, html-select

I am looking for a method to select an item from a drop down menu from my website by using RestKit API. I searched the web but it doesn't give me a relevant result. here is the HTML code for the drop down menu:

```
<form class="myProfile" method="POST">
    <div class="myProfile">Which one is your favorite soccer team?
    <select class="team_selection" name="favTeamID" id="favTeamID" onchange="JavaScript:submit()">
<option value="">Select One...</option>
<option value="203">Manchester</option>
<option value="1">Barcelona</option>
<option value="2">Chelsea</option>
</select>
```

I tried to POST on key values "name" and "id" by using following code:

```
[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://MyWebsite.com"];

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Barcelona", @"name",
                            @"1", @"id",
                            nil];

    RKRequest *request = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/profile.php" params:params delegate:self];
    [request setUserData:@"selectFavoriteTeam"];
```

But it's not working. I would appreciate if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I have to POST on favTeamID
here is the code:

```
[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://MyWebsite.com"];

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"1", @"favTeamID",
                            nil];

    RKRequest *request = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/profile.php" params:params delegate:self];
    [request setUserData:@"selectFavoriteTeam"];
```